# What are the existing AI methods to approach 3D volumes of computed tomography?

Tags: classification, image-segmentation

I have a dataset which consists of computed tomography images (CT scans) of parts that contain pores and cracks. The sets for each part are of about 1100 * 1100 * 3000-ish resolution. Currently, I use a method of thresholding and calculations to find the volumes and locations of these defects, and I would like to reproduce those results with a machine learning approach.

What are the methods known for this type of problem, and what are your general recommendations?

Edit:

- Here is the current method I am using :
  [image: Current approach]
- And this is what I aim to achieve :
  [image: Desired outcome]

Comment: Hello. To give a more concrete idea of your problem, you could post an example of an image that you have and what you want to find in the image.

Comment: I will edit post to include more details.

Comment: I added images from the data set and outputs.